# How do I delay one loop while the other runs independantly?

Tags: python

```
import time
i = 1

def sendData(x):
    time.sleep(5)
    print("delayed data: ", x)

while (1):
    print(i)
    sendData(i)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

What I want is to print a value every 5 seconds while the infinite loop runs.
so I can see the values printing very .5 seconds and another value being printed every 5 seconds.
At the moment, the loop still gets delayed because of the time.sleep(5) in the helper function. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to run two concurrent threads of execution? Like run two while loops at the same time?

Comment: So you have to print values at two different time intervals?

Comment: To accomplish this, you need to use multi-threading. You could schedule a thread using [the schedule library](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or you could use [Python's built-in threading library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: @barryodev I'm not sure about running 2 while loops at the same time but I guess I expect that helper function to be running whilst the while loop is running too.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve your goal using the `threading` library. It allows you to run code in the "background" while your main code runs alongside it.

Here's an example of how to run the `sendData` function in the background with the main loop executing concurrently. Notice that I modified `sendData` to use the global variable `i` instead of receiving it as a parameter to allow the main loop to update `i`.

```python
import threading
import time
i = 1

def sendData():
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        print("delayed data: ", i)

thread = threading.Thread(target=sendData)
thread.start()

while (1):
    print(i)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

You can read more about [threading](https://superfastpython.com/run-function-in-new-thread/) and [sharing variables](https://superfastpython.com/thread-share-variables/) when using threading.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I made a mistake and I apologize. I forgot to mention what if I needed the value x from the main while loop?

Comment: ```
   thread = threading.Thread(target=sendData, args=[i])
   thread.start()
``` from inside of the loop

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with an asynchronous approach or use multi-[threading|procesiing]

Your approach is blocking the execution as it runs step by step.
Choosing the approach depends on the task that you want to perform in the sendData method, but from the name, I could suggest asyncio should work just fine.

```py
import asyncio


async def send_data(x):
    await asyncio.sleep(5) # Could be network request as well
    print("delayed data: ", x)


async def main():
    i = 1
    while True:
        print(i)
        # Create non blocking task (run in background)
        asyncio.create_task(send_data(i))  
        i += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you. But, you need to modify them as you want

```
# importing module
import time
 
 
# running loop from 0 to 4
for i in range(0,5):
   
  # printing numbers
  print("delayed data: ", i)
   
  # adding 0.5 seconds time delay
  time.sleep(0.5)
```

the output print every 0.5 sec like this:

```
delayed data:  0
delayed data:  1
delayed data:  2
delayed data:  3
delayed data:  4
```